# Node equivalent to "-javaagent" in Java

Tags: node.js, agent, open-telemetry

`/bin/node -r /opt/otel/node/otel-agent.js /opt/service/dist/main.js`

This is how I am running my application currently.

The problem is, sometimes `otel-agent.js` **might not exist** and I want to be able to define a 'Node' agent similar to how you can define various runtime arguments via the env variable

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=javaagent:/opt/otel/java/aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar`.

Does such a thing exist for Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NODE_OPTIONS=--require /opt/otel/otel-agent.js

Answer (score 0):

There is no agent for javascript in OpenTelemetry.

As an alternative, you can use auto instrumentation modules, I would start by looking at the docs for that: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/nodejs/#instrumentation-modules

Comment: I am doing all my auto-instrumentation in otel-agent.js. It is acting as the agent.